# Your child likes to play around with his food. Is it natural to say "could you eat seriously?"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

This is what Vietnamese parents often say to children in Vietnamese "**eat seriously**" (literally translated from Vietnamese to English) when the children like to play around with his food without paying attention to their meals.

Is it natural to say "**could you eat seriously?**"?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't idiomatic to say "eat seriously".

We would say "eat sensibly" or "could you eat sensibly".

We could also say "stop playing with your food".